# Netbook can nolonger connect to TV using HDMI

Tags: windows-7, hdmi, netbook

My Windows 7 Home Acer Netbook used to be able to connect to my Teac tv via HDMI when I first got it, however it has just stopped connecting after several months for some reason.

For a while, I had to turn the tv on first, then restart the netbook to get it to connect, as Pressing Win+P (second screen only) nolonger worked. However this work around doesn't work anymore.

There are no errors in the Windows System Events panel, and I've tried upgrading to the lastest graphics driver.

This if frustrating as it should just work. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone into your screen resolution settings (Right-click the desktop, click Screen Resolution) and ensured that the second display is activated?

If it appears that there are two displays and one is greyed out, click it and select the option to extend your desktop onto that display.

Comment: Yes I've tried and it's didn't work. Pressing Windows+P(Projector), and selecting Extend should do the same thing.

Comment: @user1491819 very very rarely, HDMI cables can fail. Try swapping it with a spare and see if that fixes it, but don't keep your hopes up about that. Check your TV to see if it has any settings regarding HDMI connectivity - it might not be informing the laptop that it is recieving signal

Comment: If I plug in another laptop with the same HDMI cable it works fine.